# Getting NSum to go to the right depth in recursive definitions

Tags: plotting, numerics, summation, recursion

I wanted to produce some plots of the action of the [Gauss shift map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Kuzmin%E2%80%93Wirsing_operator) on cumulative distribution functions. This means I wanted to plot functions $F_n(x)$, for $0 \leq x \leq 1$, defined by $F_1(x) = x$ and 
$$F_{n+1}(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( F_{n}\left( \tfrac{1}{k} \right) - F_n\left( \tfrac{1}{k+x} \right) \right).$$
The $F_n(x)$'s are cumulative distribution functions, meaning they increase monotonically from $F_n(0)=0$ to $F_n(1)=1$.

Here is my first attempt:

```
f[n_, x_] := If[n == 1, x, Sum[f[n - 1, 1/k] - f[n - 1, 1/(k + x)], {k, 1, Infinity}]]
```

This computes `f[2,x]` just fine and even gives a closed form `EulerGamma + PolyGamma[0, 1 + x]`. But trying `Plot[f[3, x], {x, 0, 1}]` gives the error "Sum: Sum does not converge".

Here is my second attempt:

```
g[n_, x_] := If[n == 1, x, Sum[g[n - 1, 1/k] - g[n - 1, 1/(k + x)], {k, 1, 20}]]
```

Now the functions plot fine, but it is visibly obvious that `g[2, 1]` and `g[3, 1]` are significantly less than $1$, being about $0.95$ and $0.88$ respectively. If I try raising the bound 20 high enough to solve this, the sum takes too long to compute.

Here is my third attempt:

```
h[n_, x_] := If[n == 1, x, NSum[h[n - 1, 1/k] - h[n - 1, 1/(k + x)], {k, 1, Infinity}]]
```

Now `Plot[h[3, x], {x, 0, 1}]` produces an empty plot. Trying `Plot[Evaluate[h[3, x]], {x, 0, 1}]` runs forever without returning. I also tried the `f[n_, x_] := f[n, x] =` trick in all of these variants without success.

What I think I want is a version of `NSum` which is intelligent enough to only go as deep in the sum as necessary to make the plot. Is there a way to do this, or some other good way to approach the problem?

Comment: The two definitions only differ in that the LaTeX writes $F_{n+1}$ as a sum of $F_n$'s and the Mathematica writes f[n] as a sum of f[n-1]. Since n is a dummy variable, they are equivalent.

Comment: If you'll accept a link of questionable legality, see page 362, equation (23) of https://doc.lagout.org/science/0_Computer%20Science/2_Algorithms/The%20Art%20of%20Computer%20Programming%20%28vol.%202_%20Seminumerical%20Algorithms%29%20%283rd%20ed.%29%20%5BKnuth%201997-11-14%5D.pdf

Comment: Indeed your Latex definition doesn't agree with your code. Please check your parenthesis.

Comment: Oh, it's the LaTeX that's buggy! Thanks.

Comment: @DES Thank you for fixing the formula. The link to the definition you provided in comments unfortunately doesn’t work for me (it gets stuck tying to load and never shows anything).